# onerror in remote script tag: How to get error details?

Tags: javascript, script-tag, onerror

I have an anonymous remote `<script>` tag and want to give the user helpful feedback if it does not load. However, the event received seems overly generic.

```html
<html><body>

<script>
function Fail(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
</script>

<script src="http://localhost:55555"
        onerror="Fail(event)">
</script>

</body></html>
```

How can my `Fail()` function get a helpful error message like "connection refused", "subresource integrity check failed", etc. (depending on the situation), in order to display something helpful on the page?

Comment: This is most likely not possible for security reasons. But whom do you mean by "user" that you "want to give helpful feedback"? It would take a developer to fix this problem, and they would know to look in the browser's devtools already.

Comment: @Bergi  Re: "It would take a developer to fix this problem, and they would know to look in the browser's devtools already." OK, but your developers (and customers) are going to start charging by the hour, because 1. It takes a developer to *fix* the problem but maybe the end-user is calling the developer for support. Ideally this call doesn't involve wasting time on opening up devtools when the problem might be somewhere else. 2. So what if the developer knows to open devtools. That doesn't always make this particular step a good use of the developer's time.